# How to connect a 1mA IR receiver with a 20mA led in the same circuit?

Tags: current

[image: ir reciever][datasheet of ir reciever](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0672/9409/files/VS1838b_DS.pdf?728)[image: my circuit components]

[image]

I tried connecting them in parallel and in series but neither gives correct amperage to the components

Comment: we are not mind readers. Give us a schematic so we know what you tried to do and how you tried to do it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by connecting these parts to each other?

Comment: -The photon . Making a circuit that receives infrared and lights led when receiving infrared

Comment: use it like a transistor with current gain 0.3 to 1  ..ok?  Read the datasheet

Comment: -tony Stewart.... I am a beginner in electronics .... I know the current gain factor in the npn transistor but isnt there other way?

Comment: A transistor is possibly the best way, not to interfere with the signal itself AND having enough current for the LED to be powered on

Comment: Thanks Michel.... But which type of transistor should I use ? The npn or the pnp

Comment: What is that "IR receiver"?  Can you show us where it came from, to give us a hint?

Comment: I have a similar datasheet to this model in English... As the original datasheet is chinese

Answer (score 3):

Typical IR receiver needs a supply voltage between 2.5V ... 5.5V. Therefore you cannot use the 9V battery directly.

As for the circuit, you could try one of these circuits.

[image]

You can use any small-signal PNP you have in a TO-92 package.

And without any resistor, my IR receiver gives 15mA max of current through the LED at 5V supply. This is why I skip the resistor in the first circuit. But for safety maybe you should add one.

EDIT

I played with this circuit and I add a capacitor to make a diode to light longer.

[image]

Because without this capacitor diode lights-up for a very short period of time.

Comment: To elaborate for the OP, the IR receiver has three terminals, two for power, and one for the output. . In G36's receiver, the receiver takes two pins for power to allow it to function, and has a third pin for the output.

Comment: But in the OP's schematic, the OP has drawn the IR receiver almost as if it is a magical switch that closes to pass a signal when an IR signal is received. But this is flawed, because it implicitly assumes the receiver doesn't require any power to run its internal mechanisms. A photo-resistor might behave that way, but most "fancier" components do not.

Comment: And in many IR receivers, the receiver might only connect or disconnect the output pin from GND in the presence or absence of an IR signal. The output pin is not connected to anything when disconnected from GND. It cannot connect OUT to +V in that case.  In that case you need a pull-up resistor to pull the pin HI if you wish to output a logic signal. G36's IR receiver left has the pull-up resistor integrated (it is the vertical rectangle inside the receiver).

Comment: But for lighting an LED, you don't care about logic HI or LO. You care if current flows or not through the LED. In which case the IR receiver would look much like G36's right schematic but T1 is *inside* the IR receiver. And the top pin of T1 would be the IR receiver's OUT pin.

Comment: In the datasheet provided by OP https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0672/9409/files/VS1838b_DS.pdf?728 It seems that there is an internal pull-up resistor. But the datasheet is also showing the external pull-up resistor.  And I tested the circuit using TSOP31236 with the internal pull-up resistor (30k).

Comment: For my last response, I should clarify that the it looks like the right schematic with T1 inside the receiver if the receiver does not have an internal pull-up

Comment: @DKNguyen ... So how do I make this ir reciever like a logic hi or lo ... Not lighting the led (only) when receiving ir signal .. this is the objective I want to reach

Comment: @Tera_Byte you add a pull up resistor if it doesnt already have one. no current flow means no voltage drop across the resistor which means the voltage at both ends of the ressistor are the same